# What is the difference between Google's API-Key, OAuth Client ID and AWS Secure Token Service

Tags: encryption

What is the difference between Google's API-Key, OAuth Client ID and AWS Secure Token Service?

Are they are all just providing delegation tokens, except they are from different companies? Is there a bigger difference between them?

Comment: What do you mean with "API-key"? It seems a *generic term* for a key used to authenticate a program / user / whatever for it to get access to an API. You cannot compare a term to well defined protocols (although to make them truly well defined, you might want to point to the specs and version number). This is a very specialized still broad question. I might need to migrate it to e.g. the security site. But for that to happen, you need to first explain the API-key part.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys

Comment: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/ "GoogleAPI Key" is "OAuth Client ID" it's not really "crypto" it's just "hard to guess"